# SOQL aggregate maxing out SOQL limits

Tags: soql, governorlimits, user, login-history

I'm having trouble with my SOQL, running into SOQL limits in production.
My SOQL is counting all active Users grouped by their Freeze status. How do I re-write the following SOQL without a subquery. Instead of a subquery I tried User.IsActive = true. That didn't work.

```
  SELECT count(Id) CountOfUsers,  IsFrozen FreezeStatus, max(LastModifiedDate) LastModified FROM UserLogin WHERE UserId IN 
                          (SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = true) group by IsFrozen.
```

Looks like the subquery is causing the max out eventhough I'm returning an aggregate of 2 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows from your `Left Inner Join` do not count against your governors. If you're running into row limits, it is strictly because you have too many `UserLogin` records.

If you want to know the number of `User` records, query on `User`. You can use the same type of join, just in the other direction.

```
Integer frozenUserCount = [
    SELECT count() FROM User WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT UserId FROM UserLogin WHERE IsFrozen = true
    )
];
Datetime frozenLastModified = [
    SELECT LastModifiedDate
    FROM UserLogin
    WHERE IsFrozen = true
    ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC
    LIMIT 1
].LastModifiedDate;

Integer notFrozenUserCount = [
    SELECT count() FROM User WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT UserId FROM UserLogin WHERE IsFrozen = false
    )
];
Datetime notFrozenLastModified = [
    SELECT LastModifiedDate
    FROM UserLogin
    WHERE IsFrozen = false
    ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC
    LIMIT 1
].LastModifiedDate;
```

Comment: this is great! I didn't even think about this. When I tried executing the aggregate twice in anonymous apex, I was getting the SOQL limit warning. Even though the aggregate was returning 2 rows. When I ran the statement only once, I did not get the error. I was concerned we will reach the SOQL limit if we get more users.

Comment: @Donald even if there is only one `AggregateResult`, each record which goes into it is what gets added up for your governor usage.